# How to embed grandchild object as sonata_type_admin

Tags: symfony, orm, sonata-admin

I want to access a grandchild of my 'Technician' Entity

Hierarchy:

**Entity User** -> PersonalDetails

**Entity Technician** -> User

When attempting

```
/** AdminBundle/Admin/TechnicianAdmin.php */ 

$formMapper
    ->add('user.personalDetails','sonata_type_admin',[
         'delete'=>false
    ]);
```

I get this error

> Neither the property "personalDetailsuser" nor one of the methods "getPersonalDetailsuser()", "personalDetailsuser()", "isPersonalDetailsuser()", "hasPersonalDetailsuser()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Technician".

However attempting this:

```
/** AdminBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php */ 

$formMapper
    ->add('personalDetails','sonata_type_admin',[
         'delete'=>false
    ]);
```

Everythings works 100% as expected. I can embed PersonalDetails as a `sonata_type_admin` in my UserAdmin class, but not in my TechnicianAdmin class [ which contains a User object ]. How can I embed PersonalDetails in my TechnicianAdmin class? I hope I'm being clear please let me know any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding a getter and setter to the entity `Technician` e.g.

```
/** AppBundle/Entity/Technician.php */

// getter 
getPersonalDetails () {
    return $this->getUser()->getPersonalDetails();
}

// setter
setPersonalDetails(PersonalDetails $personalDetails) {
    $this->getUser()->setPersonalDetails($personalDetails);
}
```

and define the field in the `TechnicianAdmin`:

```
/** AdminBundle/Admin/TechnicianAdmin.php */ 

$formMapper
    ->add('personalDetails','sonata_type_admin',[
         'delete'=>false
]);
```